# Remove unsafe-eval from CSP header from backend and want to add in frontend

Tags: javascript, angular

```html
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg==" src="/fico/js/jquery.min.js?_=1686640599583"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg==" src="/fico/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1686640599583"></script>

<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/npmcdn.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.26/dist/zone.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.3/bundles/Rx.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.2/bundles/core.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/npmcdn.com/@angular/common@2.0.2/bundles/common.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/npmcdn.com/@angular/compiler@2.0.2/bundles/compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser@2.0.2/bundles/platform-browser.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.2/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/npmcdn.com/@angular/forms@2.0.2/bundles/forms.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/utilities.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/container-min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/datasource-min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/datatable-min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/calendar-min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/date.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/adeptra.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/common/xss-filters.1.2.7.min.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="/agent/PhoneFormat.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="consentRegistry.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='unsafe-eval'" type="text/javascript" src="consentContactDetails.js?_=1686640599584"></script>
<script nonce="0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg==" language="javascript">
```

In the above code i am using angular lib and it's very old code, we do not have index.html file they are manually download  and using it. how i can pass the unsafe-eval while importing this library file.

i have tried to add in with nonce value but its giving same error.

```
ERROR
zone.min.js?_=1686640599584:1 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-0ZshCIvzxPX6s9n1bpbscg=='".

    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at evalExpression (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584:6:1473)
    at jitStatements (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584:21:30062)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileModule (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584:41:18413)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584:41:16590)
    at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584:41:16063)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584:35:26523)
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.umd.min.js?_=1686640599584:35:25813)
    at Object.initAngularComponents (consentRegistry.js?_=1686640599584:415:47)
    at Object.init (consentRegistry.js?_=1686640599584:63:22)
```